# Access bLocked: App_Name request is Invalid

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api, google-signin

I am trying to add a Google backup option in my Flutter app using the Google Drive API. When the user clicks on the backup button, I am calling the uploadFileToGoogleDrive() function, which uploads a file to Google Drive.My aim is to allow users to back up their data to Google Drive by clicking on a backup button. However, I am getting the following error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
class SecureStorage {
  final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

  //Save Credentials
  Future saveCredentials(AccessToken token, String refreshToken) async {
    print(token.expiry.toIso8601String());
    await storage.write(key: "type", value: token.type);
    await storage.write(key: "data", value: token.data);
    await storage.write(key: "expiry", value: token.expiry.toString());
    await storage.write(key: "refreshToken", value: refreshToken);
  }

  //Get Saved Credentials
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> getCredentials() async {
    var result = await storage.readAll();
    if (result.isEmpty) return null;
    return result;
  }

  //Clear Saved Credentials
  Future clear() {
    return storage.deleteAll();
  }
}

const _clientId = "###.apps.googleusercontent.com";
const _scopes = [ga.DriveApi.driveFileScope];


class GoogleDrive {
  final storage = SecureStorage();
  //Get Authenticated Http Client
  Future<http.Client?> getHttpClient() async {
    //Get Credentials
    var credentials = await storage.getCredentials();
    if (credentials == null) {
      try {
        //Needs user authentication
        var authClient = await clientViaUserConsent(
            ClientId(_clientId),_scopes, (url) {
          //Open Url in Browser
          launch(url);
        });
        //Save Credentials
        await storage.saveCredentials(authClient.credentials.accessToken,
            authClient.credentials.refreshToken!);
        print(authClient);
        return authClient;
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error getting user consent: $e');
        // Show a message to the user that the authentication process failed
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      print(credentials["expiry"]);
      //Already authenticated
      return authenticatedClient(
          http.Client(),
          AccessCredentials(
              AccessToken(credentials["type"], credentials["data"],
                  DateTime.tryParse(credentials["expiry"])!),
              credentials["refreshToken"],
              _scopes));

    }
  }



  Future<String?> _getFolderId(ga.DriveApi driveApi) async {
    final mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
    String folderName = "NewFodler";

    try {
      final found = await driveApi.files.list(
        q: "mimeType = '$mimeType' and name = '$folderName'",
        $fields: "files(id, name)",
      );
      final files = found.files;
      if (files == null) {
        print("Sign-in first Error");
        return null;
      }

      // The folder already exists
      if (files.isNotEmpty) {
        return files.first.id;
      }

      // Create a folder
      ga.File folder = ga.File();
      folder.name = folderName;
      folder.mimeType = mimeType;
      final folderCreation = await driveApi.files.create(folder);
      print("Folder ID: ${folderCreation.id}");

      return folderCreation.id;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }


  uploadFileToGoogleDrive(File file) async {
    var client = await getHttpClient();
    var drive = ga.DriveApi(client!);
    String? folderId =  await _getFolderId(drive);
    if(folderId == null){
      print("Sign-in first Error");
    }else {
      ga.File fileToUpload = ga.File();
      fileToUpload.parents = [folderId];
      fileToUpload.name = p.basename(file.absolute.path);
      var response = await drive.files.create(
        fileToUpload,
        uploadMedia: ga.Media(file.openRead(), file.lengthSync()),
      );
      print(response);
    }

  }
}
```

And here is the code when the user clicks the button:

```
final appDocumentDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
googleDrive.uploadFileToGoogleDrive(File(weekBox.path.toString()));
```

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.